# there exist infinite many $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $S_n-[S_n]<\frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions, conjectures, harmonic-numbers

**recent conjecture** ：Let $S_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}$, where $n$ is a positive integer. Prove that ：there exist infinite many $n\in\mathbb{N^{+}}$ such that
$$S_n-[S_n]<\dfrac{1}{n^2}$$
where $[x]$ represents the largest integer not exceeding $x$.

previous problem:[How to prove that $a<S_n-[S_n]<b$ infinitely often](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508574/how-to-prove-that-as-n-s-nb-infinitely-often)

Comment: Can you find any example with $n \gt 1$?  Having looked at this for small $n$, I would guess there are probably no other examples.

Comment: @Henry: do you mean examples other than 1? [I didn't find any small $n.$]

Comment: @coffeemath: yes: $1$ is an example because $S_1$ is an integer.  But then the possibilities shrink geometrically or exponentially and so have a small sum beyond the values I can test in the precision limit of my machine

Comment: Heuristically this should happen a finite number of times. Consider the values $n_i$ where $\lfloor H_{n_i}\rfloor $ jumps from $i$ to $i+1$. Since $H_i\approx\ln i$, we have $n_i\approx e^i$ (this is of course a _very_ rough approximation, but that's all we need for this heuristic).  Now, at $n_i$ it's reasonable to assume (heuristically) that the fractional part $\{H_{n_i}\}$ is equidistributed in $(0, \frac1{n_i})$; this means that the probability it's less than $1/(n_i^2)$ is $\frac1{n_i}$. But then the total number of 'hits' is $\sum_i(n_i^{-1})\approx\sum_i e^{-i}$, which converges.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I don't have an intuition that suggests that $\{H_n\}$ is equidistributed in $(0, 1/n_i)$ (I haven't worked with equidistribution much, and never with something other than mod 1).  Could you provide some intuition?

Comment: @alphacapture There's nothing specific about $\{H_{n_i}\}$ here - the heuristic is that we've added $1/n_i$ to $H_{n_i-1}$ to get a number that 'rolls over' into the next integer, so we know that $\{H_{n_i}\}\geq 0$ (by definition) and $\{H_{n_i}\}\leq 1/n_i$ (because otherwise the rollover point would've been earlier); the heuristic is just in the assertion it's equidistributed within its possible range (because we have no specific reason to believe otherwise).

Comment: Formally, we can say that the set $\{\alpha \in [0,1] : (S_n+\alpha)-[S_n+\alpha] < 1/n^2 \ \text{for infinitely many} \ n \in \mathbb{N}^+\}$ has measure $0$. But showing that $0$ does not belong to this set doesn't appear to be trivial.

Comment: Article that might be useful: R. P. Boas, Jr. and J. W. Wrench, Jr., [Partial Sums of the Harmonic Series](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2316476?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), The American Mathematical Monthly. "Our problem is to compute the smallest integer $n = n_A$ for which $H_n$ exceeds a given number $A$"

Comment: @Winther: that would be $(4)$ from my answer. In that paper, they add $1$ and floor it to get the ceiling.

Comment: You should probably add to your post that you have now asked the same question on [MathOverflow]([there exist infinite many $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $S_n-[S_n]<\frac{1}{n^2}$](http://mathoverflow.net/q/258097)). See [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) and other discussions about [meta-tag:cross-posting].

Comment: I have checked all $n$ up to $2\cdot10^{10}$ and there is no $n$ such the above inequality fulfilled in that range.

Comment: @Wolfgang However my calculation show there might be one solution up to $10^{100}$.

Comment: Do you know exact value of $n$?

Comment: I calculated upperbound is 1/6, lowerbound is 1/9. This is of the expected number of solution.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki, bound for what?

Comment: @Wolfgang This is the expected number of solution which the case is 1/n^2. I calculated that by hand before your answer.

Comment: $n = 6$ or $n = 9?$. Unfortunately this are not answers because $$\Delta(S_n) = 0.45$$ and 0.82... respectively.

Comment: I've made a long answer with numerical tables at http://mathoverflow.net/a/260669/7710

Answer (score 20):

This is a heuristic argument. It does not show that there are not infinitely many occurrences, just that without some unforeseen conditions, the probability of infinitely many occurrences is zero.

---

The [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) says that
$$
H_n=\log(n)+\gamma+\frac1{2n}-\frac1{12n^2}+\frac1{120n^4}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^6}\right)\tag{1}
$$
Subtracting $\gamma$ and exponentiating gives
$$
\begin{align}
e^{H_n-\gamma}
&=ne^{\frac1{2n}-\frac1{12n^2}+\frac1{120n^4}}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^5}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+\frac5{24n^3}-\frac1{16n^4}+\frac{47}{5760n^5}+\frac1{2304n^6}\right)^{-1}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^5}\right)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Inversion of the power series $y=x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{5x^3}{24}-\frac{x^4}{16}+\frac{47x^5}{5760}+\frac{x^6}{2304}$ says
$$
x=y+\frac{y^2}2+\frac{7y^3}{24}+\frac{y^4}6+\frac{523y^5}{5760}+\frac{y^6}{20}+O\!\left(y^7\right)\tag{3}
$$
where $x=\frac1n$ and $y=e^{\gamma-H_n}$. Taking the reciprocal of $(3)$ yields
$$
n=e^{H_n-\gamma}-\frac12-\frac1{24}e^{\gamma-H_n}+\frac3{640}e^{3\gamma-3H_n}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^5}\right)\tag{4}
$$
To find an $n$ so that the fractional part of $H_n$ is less than $\frac1{n^2}$, we need to find an $H_n$ so that the fractional part of $n$ is greater than $1-\frac1n$.
$$
\begin{array}{r|r}
H_n&n\\\hline
1&1.000000000000\\
2&3.638675849525\\
3&10.773523676598\\
4&30.153290055642\\
5&82.827475640215\\
6&226.008738099299\\
7&615.215019121592\\
8&1673.187107043897\\
9&4549.053308117194
\end{array}\tag{5}
$$
Without a reason that the fractional part of $(4)$ not be uniformly distributed, the probability that the fractional part of $H_n$ is less than $\frac1{n^2}$ would be
$$
\frac1n\approx e^{\gamma-H_n}\tag{6}
$$
and since
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{H_n=1}^\infty e^{\gamma-H_n}
&=\frac{e^\gamma}{e-1}\\
&\lt\infty\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
[Borel-Cantelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) says that the probability that there are infinitely many $n$ so that the fractional part of $H_n$ is less than $\frac1{n^2}$ is $0$.

Comment: How much chance that the Pythagorean Theorem is true? I guess someone can give a probabilistic "proof" that it is zero too.

Comment: I explicitly said that this was not a proof, that it was only heuristic. If someone posts a proof, this would serve to enhance the wonder because the odds are against it. If nothing else, the inverse of the harmonic numbers was worth the exercise for me.

Comment: I hope that some of the results that I have gotten, while they don't settle the question, are helpful to someone.

Comment: Sure Rob, but I only wanted to point out that one has to be _careful_ with transfer of probabilistic arguments to environments where they do not really belong.

Comment: Huh, How'd you invert the series?

Comment: @SimpleArt: It's not too difficult if you work mod $x^2$ to get the coefficient of $x$. Then fixing that coefficient, work mod $x^3$ to get the coefficient of $x^2$. Then fixing those coefficients, work mod $x^4$ to get the coefficient of $x^3$. And so on. This algorithm is implemented in most CAS programs.

Comment: Hm, interesting...

Comment: @SimpleArt: as long as you can compose power series, which is much easier when there is no constant term.

Comment: Related to your table $(5)$ is the set of $n$ values where the fractional part of $H_n$ jumps to the next integer. These are the $n$ where one would search for an example. See [OEIS A002387](http://oeis.org/A002387) for some related comments.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Yes.

Comment: @HandeBruijn Out of curiosity, how do you (propose to) cast the Pythagorean Theorem in such a form as to be able to apply probabilistic heuristics to it?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for posting as answer but I think it would be more convenient here.
Firstly, I am offering to change the title of the question to ''There is no $n$ such ... ''. It might be more attractive.
Secondly, I have the following generalized conjecture:

> Let $M$ be the set of all $n$ such that 
>   $$H_n - \lfloor{H_n\rfloor} < \frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}.$$
>   Then 
>   $$\forall\epsilon>0 : |M| = \bar\eta(\epsilon) < \infty.$$

Also I suspect that $\bar\eta$ monotonically decreasing function on $(0,1]$.
Below I presented possible values of $\bar\eta$ ('possible' because I am not able to check all $n$'s). Actually, I was checking only up to $10^5$ first $n$'s.[image: points_eta] Next, I tried all $n$'s up to $10^6$.[image: points_eta6] **Note** that I assume $H_n$ starts with $\frac12$, not with 1.

Comment: Obviously false. $S_n-[S_n]<\frac1n$ holds about every n of $S_n-[S_n]<m<S_{n+1}-[S_{n+1}]$.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: However even the case of $\frac1{n^2}$, now anyone can't say there doesn't exist one solution. As I say, we need to search up to $10^{100}$. Although you claim this conjecture holds even If n can be reduce consectively, there is not such a logic in your answer. Of course to find such a logic is more hard than solving this conjecture.

Comment: So. What logic is behind the statement of this question?

Comment: Do you claim $ε$ is $0.8$?

Comment: May be I do not understand your question, but in presented graphs $\epsilon \in [0.01, 1.1)$ with step equals 0.01 . P.S. In my previous  comment I said about main question.

Comment: That's almost same to my first comment, though.